Create a SignalR Core in Windows Service and connect it in C# application locally
I have successfully created the SignalR connection in my Windows Service. It's working fine but when I try to connect to it through other Windows Application (.NET 4.8) by using Microsoft.AspDotNet.SignalR.Client, it doesn't actually work. It keeps getting stuck when starting the connection.
Here are the code I used:
In windows service:
var _ServiceSignalR = WebApp.Start<Startup>("http://localhost:8585");
var ServiceHubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ServiceHub>();

Startup.cs:
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.MapSignalR(new HubConfiguration { EnableDetailedErrors = true});
    }
}

ServiceHub.cs:
[HubName("ServiceHub")]
public class ServiceHub : Hub
{
        public override Task OnConnected()
        {
            //Should reach here..
            return base.OnConnected();
        }
}

That was for the windows service part. The next part is for the client-side, noticing that the client side and windows service are both .NET 4.8 (Not .NET Core)
Implementation in Client side:
var serviceHubConnectionx = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .WithUrl("http://localhost:8585/signalr")
    .Build();
await serviceHubConnectionx.StartAsync(); //It's getting stuck here forever!

I tried to use AspNet.SignalR.Client and see it goes cause I was be able to create hub proxy through it, and it worked! but it's using AspNet.SignalR.Client not AspNetCore which I need because it has more helpful features there like firing OnDisconnected once the program get closed and can return values from firing methods on client side and more..
The code I used with AspNet.SignalR.Client:
var serviceHubConnection = new HubConnection("http://localhost:8585/signalr", useDefaultUrl: false);
var serviceHubProxy = serviceHubConnection.CreateHubProxy("ServiceHub");
await serviceHubConnection.Start(); //Works instantly.

So is there anyway I can use AspNetCore.SignalR.Client in this situation?
Thanks.

We cannot directly use AspNetCore.SignalR.Client to connect to the signalr server built on ASP.NET SignalR .

@JasonPan Yeah, that's what I have noticed, but do you think there is any way to somehow achieve that? Or at least have the same features, like detecting when disconnected and returning a value for the invoked method on the client side?

Can you give more details about the error?
If the client does not send an initial handshake message, the connection will be terminated.
Send the following message when connecting
{"protocol":"json","version":1}

Hope this helps!

Doesn't have any error message! It just can't connect, like it can't reach the hub!
